# How to mute an email thread in Google Inbox mobile web app?

Tags: inbox-by-gmail, mute

In Gmail, email threads can be [muted](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/47787?hl=en).

How can they be muted in the [Google Inbox](https://www.google.com/inbox/) mobile web interface?

Comment: As this question has been reworded to be about the web interface, I've voted to re-open.

Comment: Even though my initial personal need was in the Android app, this question is relevant to the mobile web app as well. I've reworded this question to be specifically about the web app.

Answer (score 1):

In the Inbox web UI there is no menu option for Mute, but you can use the <kbd>M</kbd> key. Sorry I didn't see the "mobile" part of the question before I answered.

There is no way to Mute in the mobile app AFAIK at this time.

Hitting <kbd>?</kbd> will display the keyboard shortcuts and allow you to enable / disable them.